# Derived class virtual function not executed

Tags: c++, c++-cli, virtual-functions

I am working on a Visual Solution including a C++ project and a C++/CLI project.
I have implemented a hierarchy of classes in the C++/CLI project :

Class D => Class C => Class B => Class A

=> means : is derived from

Class `A` to class `D` are not ref classes.

Class `A` contains the following method:

```
virtual int MyMethod() const;
```

`MyMethod` is also declared and implemented in class `D`:

```
int MyMethod() const;
```

I have written the following code in the C++ project:

```
A l_dObject = D();
l_dObject.MyMethod();
```

Class `A`'s `MyMethod` is executed but I expect class `D`'s `MyMethod` to be executed.
Can someone please explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's known as slicing.

You're constructing an `A` from a `D`.  `A` probably provides a copy constructor from an `A` and has no knowledge that `D` exists.  You pass the `D` to the copy constructor (as `const A&`) and the constructor happily copies from it that way.  When you're all done here, what you have is an `A`.  The `D` is killed after the assignment.

Most of the solutions to this problem involve allocations on the heap, and pointers/references.

```
A *l_dObject = new D(); // allocate our D on the heap
...
delete l_dObject; // don't forget to delete afterwards
```

Comment: To avoid this it's often recommended to forbid the copy of classes that are meant do be used polymorphically.

Answer (score 2):

```
A l_dObject = D();
```

You are slicing the object: That means you are making a copy of the `A` portion of the object and discarding the `D` portion. When dealing with polymorphic objects, you need to use a pointer or a reference to the base class. For example:

```
A* l_dObject = new D();
```

Don't forget to `delete` it later.